# Methodology to find exploit for Windows Servers

Tags: exploit, windows-server

I am following the following walk-through for a box called Sheild on Hack the Box (HTB).
https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/HackTheBox-StartingPoint-Shield

For privilege escalation, the walkthrough says "Running the sysinfo command on the meterpreter session, we notice that this is a Windows Server 2016 OS, which is vulnerable to the Rotten Potato exploit."

That's great if you know about the exploit, but my question is what's the best way to identify this if you didn't know about the exploit upfront?

I tried searching for "Server 2016" using Searchsploit, but it yielded no results.

I also ran the [Watson.ps1](https://github.com/rasta-mouse/Watson) exploit finder script, but that did not identify the Rotten Potato exploit either.

Comment: The walkthru knows it because they designed it. Just knowing the server OS is not enough, you need to know the version number or the patch level. Search for *that* will yeild results.